# condition based on other column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

here's my table

| player | team | opp | wl_g | game_id | match_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Laz | ZETA | DRX | lose | 119512 | 184456 |
| TENNN | ZETA | DRX | lose | 119512 | 184456 |
| MaKo | DRX | ZETA | win | 119512 | 184456 |
| Foxy9 | DRX | ZETA | win | 119512 | 184456 |
| Laz | ZETA | DRX | win | 119513 | 184456 |
| TENNN | ZETA | DRX | win | 119513 | 184456 |
| MaKo | DRX | ZETA | lose | 119513 | 184456 |
| Foxy9 | DRX | ZETA | lose | 119513 | 184456 |
| Laz | ZETA | DRX | lose | 119514 | 184456 |
| TENNN | ZETA | DRX | lose | 119514 | 184456 |
| MaKo | DRX | ZETA | win | 119514 | 184456 |
| Foxy9 | DRX | ZETA | win | 119514 | 184456 |

and i need to make a column based on wl_g column with same each value on match_id, im expecting to get value for new colum wl_s(a.k.a win lose for each match_id) when win on wl_g column  = 2, is equal value win on wl_s column . Here's the table that i want

| player | team | opp | wl_g | game_id | match_id | wl_s |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Laz | ZETA | DRX | lose | 119512 | 184456 | lose |
| TENNN | ZETA | DRX | lose | 119512 | 184456 | lose |
| MaKo | DRX | ZETA | win | 119512 | 184456 | win |
| Foxy9 | DRX | ZETA | win | 119512 | 184456 | win |
| Laz | ZETA | DRX | win | 119513 | 184456 | lose |
| TENNN | ZETA | DRX | win | 119513 | 184456 | lose |
| MaKo | DRX | ZETA | lose | 119513 | 184456 | win |
| Foxy9 | DRX | ZETA | lose | 119513 | 184456 | win |
| Laz | ZETA | DRX | win | 119514 | 184456 | lose |
| TENNN | ZETA | DRX | win | 119514 | 184456 | lose |
| MaKo | DRX | ZETA | lose | 119514 | 184456 | win |
| Foxy9 | DRX | ZETA | lose | 119514 | 184456 | win |

Comment: The parameters for `wl_s` are unclear. Please rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

Add the "wl_s" column based on "wl_g" and "match_id"

```
data = {
    "player": ["Laz", "TENNN", "MaKo", "Foxy9", "Laz", "TENNN", "MaKo", "Foxy9", "Laz", "TENNN", "MaKo", "Foxy9"],
    "team": ["ZETA", "ZETA", "DRX", "DRX", "ZETA", "ZETA", "DRX", "DRX", "ZETA", "ZETA", "DRX", "DRX"],
    "opp": ["DRX", "DRX", "ZETA", "ZETA", "DRX", "DRX", "ZETA", "ZETA", "DRX", "DRX", "ZETA", "ZETA"],
    "wl_g": ["lose", "lose", "win", "win", "win", "win", "lose", "lose", "lose", "lose", "win", "win"],
    "game_id": [119512, 119512, 119512, 119512, 119513, 119513, 119513, 119513, 119514, 119514, 119514, 119514],
    "match_id": [184456, 184456, 184456, 184456, 184456, 184456, 184456, 184456, 184456, 184456, 184456, 184456]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df["wl_s"] = df.groupby("match_id")["wl_g"].transform(lambda x: "win" if (x == "win").any() else "lose")

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

Comment: it looks good but i need total win = 2 from the same team